# Расселина и расщелина - в чем разница?

Tags: выбор-слова

Рас..елина в леднике. - что надо использовать? Есть ли смысловая разница?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что касается расселин/расщелин в горах, то большинство словарей говорят что это - слова-синонимы.

В то же время есть несколько словарных статей которые выделяют специальные значения слова "расщелина" именно в контексте льда и ледников:

[Научно-технический энциклопедический словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ntes/3985/%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A9%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%90):

> **РАСЩЕЛИНА**, в геологии - глубокая трещина в ЛЕДНИКЕ. Такие расщелины возникают в результате внутренних напряжений в толще ледника либо при движении льда по неровному участку почвы.

[Морской словарь](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/sea/7691/%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A9%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%90):

> **Расщелина** (Leads) — канал или проход среди льдов разного вида.

Интересно что Геологическая энциклопедия дает только определение слова [расселина](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_geolog/15519/%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%90) со ссылкой на слово "трещина":

> **РАССЕЛИНА** — открытая [трещина](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_geolog/18551) в скальных п., иногда расширенная денудацией или промытая водой.

Зато видов трещин эта энциклопедия приводит большое количество. Складывается впечатление что в этой энциклопедии именно **трещина** является базовым термином.

Comment: Я еще немного почитала по словарям, кажется, расселина происходит от "сесть" и образуется при проседании горной породы. Вместо этого, расщелина имеет общие корни с "осколок", "откалывать". Поэтому как Artemix уже написал для ледника, наверное, правильнее употреблять расщелина.

Comment: Я думаю, расщелина все-таки однокоренное с щель

Answer (score -3):

Думаю, всё-таки, расселина - это промежуток, в котором селятся, например, узкое село меж горами, а расщелина - это щель (раскол в горе или льдах, например).